# How to Migrating AWS Redis cache to Azure Cache for Redis basic version

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure-redis-cache, redis-cache

am trying to find the doc which can help me to migrate AWS Redis cache to Azure Cache for Redis basic version

Answer (score 0):

Yes! We have this document: [Migrate to Azure Cache for Redis | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-cache-for-redis/cache-migration-guide)

We'll also have a detailed migration guide coming out soon. Will update the thread with new documentation once it is out.

Comment: Hi Oury-MSFT thanks for the link, 
The document you have shared for the Redis cache which supports the premium tier but we are using the Basic tier by which this document is not helping us.

Answer (score 0):

Hi there after multiple research we found the way to export and import Redis keys for the Azure Redis Cache for Basic tier ,

we have created the Bash script to read the Keys from source and write in destination.

*this script works only for the valid key, please find the script below

#!/bin/bash

## while loops

redis-cli -c -h sourcehostname -p 6379 -a accesskey KEYS '*' | while read key; do
echo "Copying $key"
redis-cli -c -h sourcehostname -p 6379 -a Accesskeys GET $key | while read value; do
echo "Copying $value"
redis-cli -c -h Targethostname -p 6379 -a Accesskey SET $key $value
done
echo "Pasting $key"
done

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The option to use import/export is for premium only. The others should work with basic.